# How to properly mount an NFS share in Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nas, nfs

### How to properly mount an NFS share in Linux?

I have a Synology NAS which I use to share a shared folder on my local area network. I want to mount this folder on my Ubuntu desktop computer using NFS protocol. I managed to do this with `sudo mount -t nfs4 192.168.1.69:/volume1/SERVERFOLDER /LOCALFOLDER` but there are few issues.

### 1. Issue: Only works with `Map all users to admin`

I have only managed to make the share mount and work in Ubuntu using the `Map all users to admin`-option for the share. That sounds a bit dangerous to me. Is it? The NFS rules on the NAS are set as follows:

[image: NFS rules].

Can I make it work using `no squash`?

### 2. Issue: Doesn't appear in the side panel of Nautilus in Ubuntu

If I mount the shared folder to `/LOCALFOLDER`, it does not appear in the side panel of Nautilus in Ubuntu. I tried mounting the shared folder into `~/LOCALFOLDER` and the shared folder appeared in the side panel of Nautilus. Why is this? Is it recommendable to mount an NFS share into inside your home directory?

I would like to be able to unmount the drive by simply pressing the unmount icon in Nautilus.

### 3. Issue: Mounting and unmounting only work as sudo

It bugs me that I am unable to both mount and unmount the share without using `sudo`. I would like to be able to do these operations as a regular user so I would not have to use my admin password at any point. Is this possible?

### 4. Issue: Every text file is executable

Every text file inside the mounted shared folder is executable. Why is this?

### Final thoughts

The underlying issue to me seems to be that Unix permissions on my Ubuntu desktop and Synology NAS are not configured correctly. I was thinking about claiming ownership of the shared folder after it has been mounted. I don't know.

Also worth mentioning is that the option `Apply default unix permissions` is selected in the NFS settings of Control Panel in DSM.

Comment: Why is it that for example I am able to both mount and unmount an SMB share via the "eject"-icon in Nautilus without elevated priviledges? Or unmount a USB thumb drive?

Comment: I presume that by "_it only works with..._" you're referring to permissions issues rather than mount errors or anything else?

Comment: I guess they are permission issues. It mounts but I am unable to access anything in the share unless Squash is set to `Map all users to admin`.

Comment: If anyone's interested, I managed to partially solve these issues. I guess to someone more experiences with Linux this solution might've been obvious.

I managed to work my way around the squash-issue by setting the UID and GID of my Ubuntu's user to the same as the owner of the shared folder on the NAS. Synology's operating system Diskstation Manager (DSM) does not allow you to change UID and GID of a user as they have removed `usermod` and `groupmod` from DSM. I can now access the shared folder with no squash.

Comment: On my Synology the shared folders were created with owner/group of `root:root`. Did you manually change the ownership of the shares?

Comment: @ghr Yes, I think it is possible that I have changed the owner and group at some point. I don't remember for sure though.

Comment: @WaitoPiggu interesting… Mine are `drwxrwxrwx+  1 root  root` for all shares created through the UI (i.e. `/volume1/data`). Would you mind sharing the permissions/owner details for what you have? I have matching UID/GID between client and NAS for the _contents_ of the shares, but still get permission denied when trying to view mounted share contents. Wondering if it could be the `root` ownership of the top-level directory (even though they appear to be `777`)…?

Comment: @ghr Actually I remembered incorrectly, mine are owned by root as well. Example:
`drwxrwxrwx+  9 root            root              319488 Feb 17 10:28 music`

Comment: @WaitoPiggu thanks for checking. I seem to have the same setup as you in that case, but can't for the life of me get it to work. I've [posted details](https://community.synology.com/enu/forum/1/post/133994) on the Synology community forum as a starting point, so will see where that gets me

Comment: @ghr At some point I think, on my local computer, I chown'ed the mounted shared folder to my local Ubuntu user. I